# Building a checkbox list from a database query and retaining the checkbox after a form submit

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a simple form which queries a database, grabs a list of email addresses and then creates a table based on the results.  What I would like it to do is retain the checked boxes after a submission but am having trouble figuring it out based on the way I've created my table.  I can do it no problem if I manually build the table but that defeats the purpose.  Here is the code I am working with, again the only change I would like it to do is retain the checked boxes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include('include/connect.php'); ?>
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
        <div class="emailform">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <table id="emails">
                    <?php
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            unset($email);
                            $email = $row['Email'];
                    ?>
                    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </table>
                <br/><br/>
                <input id="manual" type="text" name="select[]"><br/><br/><br/>
                <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton">Select Email Addresses</button>
            </form> 
        </div>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
                if(isset($_POST['select'])){
                    $shift = $_POST['select'];
                    if (count($shift) > 1 ){
                        $list = implode(", ", $shift);
                        echo $list;
                    } else {
                        echo "$shift[0] <br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You may want to add a column or table (based on your application) to the database to see if it's been checked. Otherwise look at the input [`checked`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) attribute, I'm not sure which part you are struggling with. Sorry for W3schools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the current email in the loop exists in `$_POST['select']`, if it is, you check it, if it is not, clear the check. This check will be displayed in the input checkbox as `<?php echo $checked;?>` :

```
 <?php
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         unset($email);
         $email = $row['Email'];
         // IF EMAIL EXISTS IN $_POST, CHECK IT.
           $checked = "";
           if(isset($_POST['select'])){
                $shift = $_POST['select'];
                $list = implode(", ", $shift);
                if (strpos($list,$email)===false)
                     $checked = "";         // EMAIL NOT IN $_POST.
                else $checked = "checked";  // EMAIL IS IN $_POST.
           }
 ?>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" <?php echo $checked;?>
          value="<?php echo $email;?>"/><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Work's perfectly.  I am going to study this code to see what's going on.  I don't code in php too often.

Answer (score 1):

Check if $row['Email'] isn't empty, then output "checked" attribute.

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
unset($email);
$email = $row['Email'];
?>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="<?php echo $email;?>"<?php if($row['Email'] != false) { echo ' checked'; } ?>><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess the issue is because the name is an array "select[]" so determining the box I want to remain checked is a little confusing

Comment: Haha, i need to get myself that comment anywhere privilege ;-)